# Geocode a location and match it up to an existing overlay with Google maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I've got a great map with the circle overlay but now I want to add the functionality to geocode an address and show it on the same map to see if the address falls within the cicle.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<script>
var amsterdam=new google.maps.LatLng(52.395715,4.888916);
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:amsterdam,
  zoom:7,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
  center:amsterdam,
  radius:20000,
  strokeColor:"#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity:0.8,
  strokeWeight:2,
  fillColor:"#0000FF",
  fillOpacity:0.4
  });

myCity.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code works great.  I just can't get the extra geocoded part done.

Comment: I don't see any attempt to add the geocoder or use it.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Use the google maps api geocode service like this:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function geocode(address) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
    });
}
geocode("Wilhelminastraat 109HS")
```

This will find the latitude and longitude of your address and mark it on the map.
http://jsfiddle.net/Lawd9ety/1/

Comment: Thank you very much.  I did a few tweaks to my original page and got something I can use for sure.  I'm still playing with it and have added a marker at the center of the circle.